# How can I simulate keypress in junit test?

Tags: java, junit, keypress, awtrobot

I have this in my main class `Board` (extends `JPanel`):

```
 public class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) && (!right)) {
            left = true;
            up = false;
            down = false;
        }
  }
```

I am trying to test if left becomes true when I press the left key:

```
 @Test
 public void testKeyPressed() throws AWTException {
    Board instance = new Board();
    Robot rob = new Robot();
    instance.setFocusable(true);
    instance.requestFocus();
    rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);
    System.out.println(instance.up);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks to me like that class `extends KeyAdapter`.

Comment: Board extends Jpanel; TAdapter extends KeyAdapter; TAdapter is defined inside Board class.

Comment: How is `rob.keyPress(...)` connected to the `keyPressed(...)` method of `TAdapter`? However, you may call `instance.getTAdapter().keyPressed(...)` (if there is something like `getTAdapter()`) in your unit test directly and validate the result.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I used the first keyListener and there was no need for getTADapter() since I only had one keyListener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code that can accomplish that:

```
KeyEvent key = new KeyEvent(instance, KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0,  KeyEvent.VK_UP,'Z');
    instance.getKeyListeners()[0].keyPressed(key);
```

Comment: Useful... but only if a component has KeyListeners.  The other mechanism is the InputMap(s)-ActionMap.  For these you need to create KeyStrokes, get the IM value (String) and then get the AM value (Action)... and then go action.actionPerformed().  In my experience actionPerformed() doesn't always work as you hope...